# Detect if client is using RAW socket to send packet to server

Tags: c#, sockets, raw-sockets

Detect if client is using RAW socket to send packet to server.
Sometimes client uses WPE and other tool to send data to server.

Answer (score 2):

> Detect if client is using RAW socket to send packet to server.

You cannot detect that on the server. A useful RAW packet conforms (most likely) to the standards, like any normal TCP, UDP, ICMP or IGMP packet.

On the client, the main difference is that RAW packets require root privileges to be sent - in contrast to TCP and UDP packets. Maybe you can hook on *WinSock* on Windows and check the params, or so.